# Why does the power method converge to an eigenvector?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, numerical-linear-algebra

I'm currently working on a way to find eigenvectors analytically. The teacher suggested that I show that

$$ x_{k+1} \gets \dfrac{Ax_k}{\|Ax_k\|}$$

where $x_{k}$ is the vector and $A$ the matrix, converges to an eigenvector.

I can't seem to think of any ideas on how to prove this. Is there any literature on this?

Comment: You have to be more specific. Of which matrix do you want the eigenvectors from? $A$? This looks pretty much like a power method.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This method is known as the power iteration, you can first check that without paying attention to $0$ division, $x_n = \frac{A^nx_0}{||A^nx_0||}$.

To see what's happening let me check this convergence when A is symmetric positive and has $d$ distinct eigenvalues and $x_0$ has a non negative component with respect to the eigenvector of largest magnitude. In this case one can introduce an orthogonal basis $(v_1,...,v_d)$ of $\mathbb{R}^d$ constituted of eigenvectors associated to $A$'s eigenvalues $0 \leq \lambda_1 < ... < \lambda_{d-1} < \lambda_d$. Then by Pythagoras's formula we have for any $x \in \mathbb{R}^d$ and $n \in \mathbb{N}$,

$$\Vert A^nx\Vert^2 = \left\Vert A^n\sum_{k=1}^d \langle v_k,x \rangle v_k\right\Vert^2 = \left\Vert\sum_{k=1}^d \langle v_k,x \rangle\lambda_k^nv_k\right\Vert^2 = \sum_{k=1}^d \langle v_k,x \rangle^2\lambda_k^{2n} $$

and thus, using that $\langle v_k,x_0 \rangle > 0$,

$$\frac{A^nx_0}{\Vert A^nx_0\Vert} = \sum_{k=1}^d \frac{\langle v_k,x_0 \rangle\lambda_k^n}{\sqrt{\sum_{k=1}^d \langle v_k,x_0 \rangle^2\lambda_k^{2n}}}v_k$$

Since $(v_1,...,v_d)$ is a basis of $\mathbb{R}^d$ we only have to check each real sequence of coordinates, if $k < d$ we have

$$\frac{\langle v_k,x_0 \rangle\lambda_k^n}{\sqrt{\sum_{k=1}^d \langle v_k,x_0 \rangle^2\lambda_k^{2n}}} = \frac{\langle v_k,x_0 \rangle(\lambda_k / \lambda_d)^n}{\sqrt{\sum_{k=1}^d \langle v_k,x_0 \rangle^2(\lambda_k / \lambda_d)^{2n}}} = \frac{o(1)}{\sqrt{\langle v_k,x_0 \rangle^2 + o(1)}} \longrightarrow 0$$

and for $k = d$,

$$\frac{\langle v_d,x_0 \rangle\lambda_d^n}{\sqrt{\sum_{k=1}^d \langle v_k,x_0 \rangle^2\lambda_k^{2n}}} = \frac{\langle v_d,x_0 \rangle}{\sqrt{\langle v_k,x_0 \rangle^2 + o(1)}} \longrightarrow 1$$

This can be adapted to the case of any number of complex eigenvalues but constants may appear.

Comment: For angle brackets use`\langle` and `\rangle`.

Comment: To be sure I understand correctly : the fact that for $k = d$, the series converges to $1$ means that the whole series converges towards a particular eigenvector ?

Comment: @K.defaoite thanks for this one, I was wondering why my inner product looked so bad

Comment: @olirwin I wrote $x_n$ as a sum which number of terms is finite and constant with respect to $n$, it is $d$ the dimension of the space we are working in. I just used that in a finite dimension vector space a sequence converges if and only if all its coordinates sequences converge. Also the sequence $(x_n)$ is made to converge to $v_d$.

Comment: You can also use `\Vert` for double bars. Also you can use double dollar signs to center the math and make it a bit bigger and more readable.